# What jobs in Finance are most math intensive?

Tags: mathematics, finance-mathematics, math

I'm a math major and I've always been really interested in Finance; however, I'm starting to enjoy math more and more and would like to know which jobs in Finance use the most/more advanced math. Also, what kind of path would lead to those jobs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define advanced math from your perspective?